# vb.net - count all duplicates data in Datagridview for certain criteria and put it on a chart

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

So basically what I'm trying to do is count the duplicate values in a certain "column8" avoiding the rows that are "NO" in column17. The table would be like this:

| column8 | column17 |
| --- | --- |
| 014 | NO |
| 014 |  |
| 013 | NO |
| 013 |  |
| 014 |  |
| 017 |  |

and my code looks like this:

```
For Count As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    If DataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells("Column17").Value <> "NO" Then
        Chart1.Series(0).Points.AddXY(DataGridView1.Item(8, Count).Value, 
                                      DataGridView1.Item(8, Count).Value)
    End If
Next Count
```

It get the names, but the count doesn't made sense at all. The result that I need is the chart with the name of the column8, with how many have repeat not including the ones that have "NO" in column17. Something like this:

014 2
013 1
017 1

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use LINQ to do the following:

1. Query the DataGridViewRows
2. Where the Row is not null, is not a new row, and the respective Column17 value is not "NO"
3. Group by the Column8 value
4. Return the first group's Column8 value along with the count

This will provide you with the unique values and desired count. For example:

```vb
Dim chartValues = From row In DataGridView1.Rows.OfType(Of DataGridViewRow)
                  Where
                      row IsNot Nothing AndAlso
                      Not row.IsNewRow AndAlso
                      Not row.Cells().Item("Column17").Value.Equals("NO")
                  Group By row.Cells().Item("Column8").Value Into rowGroup = Group
                  Order By rowGroup.Count() Descending
                  Select New With {
                      .Value = rowGroup.First().Cells("Column8").Value.ToString(),
                      .Count = rowGroup.Count()
                  }
```

I am not familiar enough with the Chart control to provide you with a confident example, but I **think** you would add data in this fashion:

```vb
For Each chartValue In chartValues
    Chart1.Series(0).Points.AddXY(chartValue.Value, chartValue.Count)
Next
```

**UPDATE**

Per the OP's request, here is a non-LINQ version of the above code (sans-sort)

```vb
Dim chartValues = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
For Each row In DataGridView1.Rows.OfType(Of DataGridViewRow)
    If (row Is Nothing OrElse row.IsNewRow OrElse row.Cells().Item("Column17").Value.Equals("NO")) Then
        Continue For
    End If

    Dim column8Value = row.Cells().Item("Column8").Value.ToString()
    If (chartValues.ContainsKey(column8Value)) Then
        chartValues(column8Value) += 1
    Else
        chartValues.Add(column8Value, 1)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without LINQ? I cant use SQL, the problem that I have is that I dont know how to count the rows, thats why Im getting 0 in the chart. Thanks!

Comment: @MahoLau - Yes, you can do it without LINQ. All LINQ does in this case is provide you with a concise and easier to read looping mechanism. I will update my post to include the non-LINQ equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I get to made the chart, with this code Chart1.Series(0).Points.AddXY(chartValue.Key, chartValue.Value), it shows all the counts values, but only half the headers

Comment: @MahoLau - that sounds like something specific to the chart control. Unfortunately, I have almost never used it (I never cared for the control). I would suggest creating a new question with the following information: the code you are using, the data that is being returned, the expected behavior of the chart, and the actual behavior of the chart.